# Why should I declare objects attributes inside the constructor

Tags: java

I am trying to learn Java.

```java
public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    JButton button;

    JLabel label;

    MyFrame(){
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("point.png");

        ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon("face.png");

        label = new JLabel();

        label.setIcon(icon2);

        label.setBounds(150, 250, 150, 150);

        label.setVisible(false);

        button = new JButton();

        button.setBounds(100, 100, 250, 100);

        button.addActionListener(this);

        button.setText("I'm a button!");
```

In this class I don't know the point of declaring the buttons attributes inside the constructor. Why can't I declare the attributes globally?

Comment: You're not *declaring* the fields in the constructor. You're *assigning values to them* in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you're declaring them as a field to the class. You're assigning/instantiating them in the constructor. Because the constructor is called when an Object of that class is instantiated, you want to set these buttons and labels as soon as you make your Frame. Also, where else would you call the methods of your labels and buttons (`setIcon, setBounds, etc`) to set their attributes? You could put that in a separate method, but you'd have to call that method in the Constructor.
It's also just a matter of writing readable code. If I'm tracing code and a new object of some class is created, I can look at the Constructor to see what code is being run.

So any code that needs to be run when an Object is created goes in that Object's appropriate constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. I understand the problem now. Just one question in mind: If i set the methods global around the class like declaring the button object. They will be not called when i declare the object but they will be called when i set them inside the constructor,right?

Comment: What do you mean by "set the methods global"? What methods? What do you mean by "when i set them inside the constructor"? You don't "set" methods... it's hard to tell exactly what you mean, I'm afraid. (I know that's probably because you're new to Java - it just makes it hard to help you.) I suggest you ask a new question, ideally with simpler but complete code (a class that *isn't* part of a GUI).

Comment: I apologize for my bad explain. I wanted to mean writing the methods outside of constructor.

Comment: So I think where you're getting mixed up is thinking of Java as a functional programming language. Java is Object oriented. There isn't really a "global" part of a Java scope. A Java class has fields and methods, and other classes/objects of those classes can see them depending on the access modifier. Normally, fields are private so they are only accessible within the class. The closest thing to a global variable would be a `public static`. In short, that means any object can see it, and it is an attribute of the class itself, instead of an individual object/instance of that class.